# when i clicked a button on a wep page then activate a service on android platform

Tags: android, service, web, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem. i have a ASP.NET web page and there is a button on this web page. I want to **When i clicked the button then start an event or a service on android phone**. Actually I do not know. Is this possible.

Can you suggest me a way, algorithm or an article about this problem.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I want to when i clicked a button on a web site using computer (Not using same android device) Then start an activity or event. Is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following declaration for one of your `Activity`s to your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:pathPrefix="/startService" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/startService" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The effect is that whenever someone navigates to the page `/startService` on your website using any browser on the Android device, this will start the `Activity` that you have declared this with.

You can change the path that the user must go to by changing `android:pathPrefix`.

Then, you can use the following form (with a button) to make the user go to this page on your website:

```
<form action="/startService" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Start service" />
</form>
```

But this must happen on the same device, i.e. the user must click on the button in the Android browser and on the same device, this will start your `Activity`. You cannot start a service on a remote Android device by clicking on the button on your computer.

In your `Activity` named `MyActivity`, you can then start the `Service` via `startService()`.

Comment: Hi Marko, I want to when i clicked a button on a web site using computer, (not using same android device) Then start an activity or event. Is it possible.

Comment: This is possible as well, as AirDroid is doing this, for example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid Nevertheless, it is much more difficult than the solution above. Can't tell you how exactly, sorry.